# A RenderFlex overflowed by 19 pixels on the bottom, while scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart

In TabBarView -> Column, Iam getting this exception `A RenderFlex overflowed by 120 pixels on the bottom.`
while scrolling, It happens only on the particular part/container: TabBarView -> Column -> Container.
here is an image for better understanding [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGdCV.jpg)

here is the code for tabView.dart:

```
class TabView extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Category> categories = [
    
  ];

  final TabController tabController;

  TabView({Key key, this.tabController}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9);
    return TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: tabController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(                                   **//Exception here**
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/9,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                     // padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      //shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: categories.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) => CategoryCard(
                              category: categories[index],
                            )),),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                Flexible(child: RecommendedList()),
              ],

          ),

          Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Flexible(child: RecommendedList())
          ]),
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Flexible(child: RecommendedList())
          ]),
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Flexible(child: RecommendedList())
          ]),
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Flexible(child: RecommendedList())
          ]),
        ]);
  }
}
```

code for recommendedList.dart:

```
class RecommendedList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Product> products = [....];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(                        **//Exception here**
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 20,
           child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 8.0),
                  width: 4,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Recommended',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: darkGrey,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: Container(),
        ),//
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

These 2 classes are used in main page, here is the code:

```
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomBar(controller: bottomTabController),
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: MainBackground(),
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: bottomTabController,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: NestedScrollView(
                headerSliverBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                  // These are the slivers that show up in the "outer" scroll view.
                    return <Widget>[
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: appBar,
                      ),
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: topHeader, //child: ParallaxMain(),
                      ),
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: ProductList(
                          products: products,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: ProductList2(),
                      ),
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: tabBar,
                      ),
                    ];
                  },
                   body: Container(
                     child: TabView(
                       tabController: tabController,
                     ),
                     //: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/10,
                 ),
              ),
            ),
            CategoryListPage(),
            CheckOutPage(),
            ProfilePage()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and here is the exception i got:

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 104 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///E:/arm%20dataset/flutter_ecommerce_template-m/lib/screens/main/components/tab_view.dart:59:11
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#7b505 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=13.1)
...  size: Size(411.4, 13.1)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: min
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 19 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///E:/arm%20dataset/flutter_ecommerce_template-m/lib/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart:37:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Please help me out.

Comment: try wrapping your TabBarView/ the Column() inside SingleChildScrollView() and set the scrollDirection to ScrollDirection.vertical...

Comment: @ajs.sonawane I tried bit ended up with exception `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 590 pos 14: 'position.minScrollExtent != null && position.pixels != null': is not true.` , even wrapping with flexible/expanded is not working please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ListView` instead of `Column` should help.

Comment: Using `ListView` will allow the user to pull the contents up & down though.

Comment: @JamesPoulose you may use the physics for the behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using wrapping your `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView` widget like this?

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
```

Comment: I tried column wrapping with SingleChildScrollView(with scrolling vertical), i faced an exception like this: ` Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 590 pos 14: 'position.minScrollExtent != null && position.pixels != null': is not true.`  , I think the problem happening because of nested scroll view. I even tried expanded/Flexible it ended up with stretching the container while scrolling and other case if i wrapped with container above with height mentioning it throws the same pixel overflowed exception, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the Column widget with SingleChildScrollview should work.. Let me know if it worked for you..

Comment: I tried column wrapping with SingleChildScrollView(with scrolling vertical), i faced an exception like this: `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 590 pos 14: 'position.minScrollExtent != null && position.pixels != null': is not true`  , I think the problem happening because of nested scroll view. I even tried expanded/Flexible it ended up with stretching the container while scrolling and other case if i wrapped with container above with height mentioning it throws the same pixel overflowed exception, please help me